# How to store hash map in derby database

Tags: java, derby

I have a HashMap of a following structure:

```
HashMap<Integer, int[]> map = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
```

What is the best way to store it in derby database so I can recreate the hash map using data from the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't store the object directly, but you can serialize it to Inputstream and [insert it as a BLOB](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=1146304&seqNum=3) into your database. Then you retrieve it later and deserialize again.